# jQuery select this child

Tags: jquery, select

```
<ul>
   <li class="hoverMe"><div class="secret">Haha</div></li>
   <li class="hoverMe"><div class="secret">Blabla</div></li>
   <li class="hoverMe"><div class="secret">Tada</div></li>
</ul>
```

Secred divs are hidden in css:

```
.secret {
   display: none;
}
```

I want to display the secret child of "hoverMe" after hovering "hoverMe' (so when user hovers link number one he sees "Haha", nubmer two "Blabla" etc.).

I've tried this code and it doesn't work. I've been trying replacing "next" with "child(ren)" etc., but nothing. Any ideas?

```
 jQuery().ready(function() {

                jQuery('.hoverMe').hover(function(){
                    jQuery(this).next('.secret').Toggle();
                });
            });
```

The strange thing is (this).children() toggles all children, but when I try with (this).children('.secret') it doesn't do a thing.

Comment: you got your solution or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it ever happens to you and nothing seem to work try adding another child() to the chain, or at least check your markup to make sure that your parent element is not really a GRANDparent.

The answer was:

```
$(this).children().children().show();
```

Answer (score 2):

[hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) can bind two handlers:

```
$('.hoverMe').hover(function(){
  $(this).children().show();
}, function(){
  $(this).children().hide();
})
```

or

```
$('.hoverMe').hover(function(){
  $(this).find('.secret').show();
}, function(){
  $(this).find('.secret').hide();
})
```

or, as [@Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) kindly noticed, it can bind only one handle with:

```
$('.hoverMe').hover(
  $(this).find('.secret').toggle();
)
```

Comment: No, `hover` accepts also one handler. It will be called on entering *and* leaving, so the OPs use of it with `toggle` is perfectly fine. See the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 1):

Your `.hoverme`s are empty (have a height of 0) when `.secret`is not displayed, so there is nothing to hover over.

You'll need to use `visibility: hidden` / `visibility: visible` instead

```
.secret {
    visibility:hidden;
}

jQuery().ready(function() {
  $(".hoverMe").hover(function () {
    $(this).find(".secret").css("visibility", "visible");
  }, function () {
    $(this).find(".secret").css("visibility", "hidden");
  });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bM7f2/

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/children/

```
jQuery(this).children('.secret')[0]
```

Oh you tried that. never mind.

Answer (score 0):

- Use [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/).
- [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) needs to start with a small letter.
- **Important:** You need other **"visible"** content in the list element. Otherwise it takes up *no space* and there is nothing you can hover over. At least you would have to add an `&nbsp;`. As you can see in the demo, I added those. If you remove it, it won't work anymore.

So it should be:

```
jQuery('.hoverMe').hover(function(){
    jQuery(this).children('.secret').toggle();
});
```

Your ready handler is also wrong, must be:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //...
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/uWrR8/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $("ul li.hoverMe").hover(function(){
        $(this).children("div.secret").show();
    },
    function(){
        $(this).children("div.secret").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery().ready(function() {
                jQuery('.hoverMe').hover(function(){
                    jQuery(this).children('.secret').**t**oggle();
                });
            });
```

JS is case sensitive

Comment: And also you shouldn't use display:none in this case, cause it doesn't take any space in page wich would be responsible for hover event, you should use visibility:hidden or somehow specify dimensions ofparent element.